# @Localizer doesn't work on special case input type submit with asp-for and value

Tags: asp.net-core, post, razor, localization

I have an button on my razor page where I submit a value to my post method.
All worked as I want to

```
        <input type="submit" value="Resend Link" asp-for="@resendLink" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

in my c# I catch the value on post

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string resendLink)
```

Now I simply wanted to localize the language of the button

```
<input type="submit" value=@Localizer["Resend Link"] asp-for="@resendLink" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Localizer does not work

It works if I use it without asp-for tag or if I declare it with button tag

```
<button type="submit" asp-for="@resendLink" value="ResendLink" class="btn btn-primary">@Localizer["Resend Link"]</button>
```

However like that it does not anymore transfer the value to my post method.

How can I localize it? and still have the transfer?

Tks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.net core bind data with name attribute.As you said `It works if I use it without asp-for tag or if I declare it with button tag`.You can remove `asp-for` tag and add name attribute like this:

```
<input type="submit" value=@Localizer["Resend Link"] name="resendLink" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Comment: Great so easy if you know :-) Tks